# R ffdf sorted data

Tags: r

I want to sort the data

```
z=as.ffdf(data.frame(w=c(4,1,2,5,7,8,65,3,2,9), x=c(12,1,3,5,65,3,2,45,34,11),y=1:10))
```

I need sorted data based on columns w,x. This is much simple task, if we have a data frame.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ffdforder from package ff, this returns an ff_vector, which you can use to index your ffdf, without RAM issues.

```
require(ff)
z=as.ffdf(data.frame(w=c(4,1,2,5,7,8,65,3,2,9), x=c(12,1,3,5,65,3,2,45,34,11),y=1:10))
idx <- ffdforder(z[c("w","x")])
zordered <- z[idx, ]
zordered
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
require(ffbase)

z <- as.ffdf(data.frame(w=c(4,1,2,5,7,8,65,3,2,9),
                        x=c(12,1,3,5,65,3,2,45,34,11),y=1:10))

z[order(z$w[], z$x[]), ]
##     w  x  y
## 2   1  1  2
## 3   2  3  3
## 9   2 34  9
## 8   3 45  8
## 1   4 12  1
## 4   5  5  4
## 5   7 65  5
## 6   8  3  6
## 10  9 11 10
## 7  65  2  7
```

You can use `fforder` to order your `ffdf` without using your RAM. Credit to @jwijffels

```
z[fforder(z$w, z$x), ]
```

Comment: I am applying it on big data and it gave error "cannot allocate vector of size 256.0 Mb".

Comment: @jwijffels You are right, I didn't see an implementation of `order` or `sort` in `ff` but I'll continue to dig.

Comment: This will overblow your RAM if z is too big as it will get all data in RAM as you index based on an integer vector instead of an integer ff_vector. What you could do is use z[as.ff(order(z$w[], z$x[])), ] as this will only put w and x in RAM.

Comment: The order and sort functionalities in ff are called ffsort, ffdfsort, fforder, ffdforder

Comment: Yeah true I was looking into `ffbase` help. Thanks a lot. I updated the answer